# Running a wine game with bilinear filtering

Tags: wine

I am trying to run an old school game in an Ubuntu pc with wine.

The game runs at a fixed resolution of 640x480 and runs perfectly in full screen mode. But obviously is very pixelated.

Is there any way I can tell wine to actually apply a filter to the rendered image when in full screen so ot looks better?